# Php function is not returning the value

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to fill dynamicly a value in a form (Gravity form), so i'm using the function add filter :
`add_filter( 'gform_field_value_champp', 'test' );`
which fill the field "champp" with the return of the function test which is :

```
function test ( $fieldname)
{
    return $fieldname ;
}
```

But i don't know why, nothing is returned. If i do a  `var_dump($fieldname)`, the variable is not empty.
Despite, if i do

```
function test ( $fieldname)
{
    echo var_dump ($fieldname);
    $fieldname = "value";
    return $fieldname ;
}
```

The value "value" is well returned and it fill the form ... ! So i don't understand ...

Thanks

Comment: you need to echo the return - not use return. One of the many reasons WP sucks

Comment: seems not to work, also, now the var_dump is returning this : ```string(10) "Architecte" string(0) "" ``` but i'm only passing the string "Architecte"

Comment: var_dump does just what it does. It dumps your variable with additional informations, in this case that it is a string of the length 10. You are doing two var_dumps, the second one with an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

`var_dump()` is a 'void' function which means it does not return a value as a result of calling the function. And as such when the line:

```php
   // ...
   echo var_dump($fieldname)
   // ...
```

You are trying to `echo` an empty value.

So if you want to directly print the variable passed into the functions via the filter here's what your code would look like:

```php
function test ( $fieldname ) {

    echo $fieldname; // this is print the value of the variable

    $fieldname = "value";

    return $fieldname ;
}
```